# Basic C++ Design

Tags: c++

I have a question re my C++ class design.  Often I face little issues like this and I'd like some advice as to what is better accepted.

I have some class which monitors the temperature of some device over UDP.  If the device receives a packet of data, it is to print "x\n" to stdout to show that it received something.  Then it is to check the data in that packet and verify that the data doesn't show that the temperature of the device is too high.  If it is too high, I must call some function.  If it isn't, I must call some other function.

I'm not sure if I should do this:

```
enum temperature {TEMPERATURE_FINE, TEMPERATURE_EXCEEDED};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv + argc);

    if(!args.size())
        cout << "No parameters entered.\n";
    else
    {
        CTemperatureMonitor tempMonitor(args);

        if(tempMonitor.MonitorTemperature() == TEMPERATURE_EXCEEDED)
            tempMonitor.ActivateAlarm();
        else
            tempMonitor.DisableAlarm();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

where tempMonitor.MonitorTemperature() calls `std::cout << "x\n"`.  So `std::cout << "x\n"` is built into the class.

Or:

```
enum temperature {TEMPERATURE_FINE, TEMPERATURE_EXCEEDED};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv + argc);

    if(!args.size())
        cout << "No parameters entered.\n";
    else
    {
        CTemperatureMonitor tempMonitor(args);

        temperature tempExceeded = tempMonitor.MonitorTemperature();
        std::cout << "x\n";
        if(tempExceeded == TEMPERATURE_EXCEEDED)
            tempMonitor.ActivateAlarm();
        else
            tempMonitor.DisableAlarm();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

where `std::cout << "x\n"` is not included in the class.

The `std::cout << "x\n"` must occur before calling `CTemperatureMonitor::ActivateAlarm()` and `CTemperatureMonitor::DisableAlarm()`.

I know this might seem really minor and simplistic, but I'm often wondering what exactly should be part of the class.  Should the class be outputting to stdout?  Does it make any difference whether I do one or the other?  Am I being to pedantic about this?

Also, as an aside, I know global variable are considered poor practise.  I use the temperature enum in both the main and the class.  Should I declare it twice, once in main and once in the CTemperatureMonitor class, or once globally?  Although this question seems rather specific, it would actually clear a whole lot of other things up for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Think about single-responsibility, minimal coupling, modularity and reusability.

Comment: For me it would depend on what the line with the 'x' on it does. If it has something to do with the status of the temperature, it would be in the CTemperatureMonitor class. If it's just a division for different things, I'd keep it outside the class.

Comment: It just says, "I have received a packet".  Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'd like to point out that there are various size of projects, and that depending on the size (and criticity), the advices will actually be different. So first a rule of thumb:

> The size of the "framework" that you put in place (Logger, Option Parser, etc...) should probably not exceed 10% of the total program. After this point, it's just overkill. Unless it's the goal of the exercise!

That being said, we can start have a look at your actual questions.

---

> Also, as an aside, I know global variable are considered poor practice. I use the temperature enum in both the main and the class. Should I declare it twice, once in main and once in the CTemperatureMonitor class, or once globally?

You are actually mistaking *variables* and *types* here. *temperature* is a type (of enum kind).

In general, Types are used as bridges between various parts of the program, and to do so it is important that all those parts share the same definition of the type. Therefore, for types, it would be bad practice to actually declare it twice.

Furthermore, not all globals are evil. Global *variables* are (shared state), but global *constants* are fine, and usually play a role similar to types.

---

> I know this might seem really minor and simplistic, but I'm often wondering what exactly should be part of the class. Should the class be outputting to stdout? Does it make any difference whether I do one or the other? Am I being to pedantic about this?

There are two kinds of output:

- logging output, which is used to diagnose issues when they are encountered
- *real* output, which is *what the program does*

Depending on programs, you might have either, both or none.

From a pedantic point of view, you would generally prefer not mix those. For example, you could perfectly send the logging to a file, or `stderr` when it's serious, and use `stdout` for the "useful" stuff.

This actually drives the design somewhat, as then you need two sinks: one for each output.

Being that you have a quite simplistic program, the easiest way might be to simply pass two different `std::ostream&` to your class upon construction. Or, even simpler, just have two generic functions and use the (evil) global variables.

In larger program, you would probably design a Logger class that would have various log levels and provide specific macros to register (automatically) the function name, file name and line number of the log line. You would also probably have a lightweight logging mechanism that would allow you to disable logging `DEBUG`/`DEV` level traces in the Release builds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is quite informative.  My program has no form of logging, the cout << "x\n" is real output.  I know that May seem odd...  So given I only have one output, and it is real and it must always be to stdout, which would be preferred?

Comment: @user968243: I would recommend not to overenginner it. `std::cout` works for now, so just keep it. Even if you one day want to log in a file instead, you can still just redirect the output (and even use `tie` to log in both a file and on the console). Only introduce a logger class if you want additional functionalities (like levels of logging that can be enabled/disabled), and *at that moment* refactor your application.

Answer (score 1):

[The single level of abstraction principle](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/06/12/coding-single-level-of-abstraction-principle/) would favor doing all I/O in the same method instead of doing some at a high level and some at a low level of abstraction.

In other words, if you believe in that principle, keeping both input and output via cin/cout in the same method instead of showing some and hiding some is a good idea. It tends to give more readable code with less dependencies in each class.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), the second option is preferred (any class should have exactly one responsibility, which is monitoring the temperature in your case, not outputting the results,) though you might want to set up another class to handle the temperature monitoring results (e.g. to write the results to a certain log file or something).

Comment: It is hard to draw the line the.  For example, maybe part of monitoring the temperature is doing std::cout << "x\n"; to say that you are actually monitoring the temperature and it's working.

Comment: Of course, I'm talking about the real system design here, since the question was a general one, with the temperature monitoring being just an example (and not taking debug logging into account for that matter :)).

Comment: Yeah, I just find it hard to work out where to draw the line, when to decide that something should not be in the class.  There seems to be some definite gray areas!

Comment: Naturally! Otherwise OOD could be formalized. You just have a handful of rules, guidelines, and best practices to stick to, so that your programs will be simple (simplicity == less bugs, more understanding), easy to alter and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to have some way of logging information about your program.
It's also normal for this way to be, well, global.

Otherwise things just get too complicated when calling a method.
The only thing you should do to improve this is:

Have a logger class (or use an existing one) that can have its output stream set to whatever you choose (including std::out and an empty stream that doesn't print anything).
Ultimately, have a logger than can be hidden behind a #define so that it does not slow down code running in Release mode.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion in such cases you should not include cout into class, as maybe sometimes later you will need to output to the file or don't output at all. So if the cout is not put to the class you will have opportunity to reuse your class code without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. Responsibility of main is to start the application with the command line arguments and to give a return value. Everything else should not be there. You might want to take a look at a book like "Object Design, Roles, Responsibilities, and Collaborations"